# Why did the Virgin One launch fail?

Tags: failure, launch-vehicle, virgin-galactic, smallsat, smallsat-launcher

What caused the early shutdown of Virgin rocket's upper stage? The previous failure was also due to early shutdown of engine, although that was first stage failure. As per reports available in public, it was failure of LOX feed line for previous failure. Is the same anomaly repeated for upper stage?

Comment: It typically takes several months to investigate a rocket failure. It only happened 5 days ago. There is no way that *anybody* can answer this question, not even Virgin Orbit.

Comment: As there is no official report, any answer would be based on conjecture, therefore I'm voting to close this as opinion based.

Comment: @GdD feel free to leave an answer to [What's best to do about questions that might not be answerable for a few months?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/12102)

Comment: @JörgWMittag ditto

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the [engine overheated](https://spacenews.com/virgin-orbit-elaborates-on-potential-cause-of-launcherone-failure/#:%7E:text=The%20company%20said%20that%20components,premature%20shutdown%20of%20the%20engine.). The failure began with [an issue with a $100 part](https://www.space.com/virgin-orbit-united-kingdom-launch-failure-rocket-part), or more specifically a fuel filter. It was dislodged and therefore caused the overheating of the engine. This then prematurely shut it down. One other thing to note, it seems that faulty telemetry was at fault. Looking at the launch video, the telemetry [reported nonsensical speed and altitude](https://spacenews.com/first-virgin-orbit-u-k-launch-fails/#:%7E:text=While%20telemetry%20during%20the%20live,and%20payloads%20had%20reached%20orbit.). Combined with the fact that they orginally said that they had achieved orbit, and then around a half an hour later revised that statement, it appears that they didn't even have accurate information on the rocket and therefore were unable to attempt to fix the problem in the moment.

Comment: How would they have fixed a dislodged fuel filter?

Comment: They couldn't fix the fuel filter, they could try to find a workaround. These are very smart people. They can sometimes find solutions @OrganicMarble

Comment: I'd be fascinated to hear what options they had to work around it. If any.

Comment: We don't know since they never got the chance. Take the H3 failure. They tried to ignite it again at a different point. It was unsuccessful but still makes the point of they have a chance. The telemetry failure destroyed an knowledge whatsoever of what was actually happening in real time. @OrganicMarble

Comment: If you don't know if they had any way to work around it, why bring it up? Answers should be factual, not guesses.

Comment: I bring it up as this is why they didnt try to salvage the mission, which they normally do. Also as a this was another failure that possibility stopped them from saving the mission@OrganicMarble

Comment: The question is about the engine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144520/discussion-between-starship-is-go-for-launch-and-organic-marble).

Comment: Upvoted.  How are you generating your links?  I just noticed that the URIs contain a "text" parameter that looks like it should act like a deep link (i.e. citing a particular part of the text).  It doesn't seem to work on Firefox, but that's pretty neat.

Comment: Thank you. How am I generating my links? Using the links button in the answer/edit screen @ErinAnne

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear; I meant getting the URLs as you have them (e.g. https://spacenews.com/virgin-orbit-elaborates-on-potential-cause-of-launcherone-failure/#:%7E:text=The%20company%20said%20that%20components,premature%20shutdown%20of%20the%20engine. ).  Share function in a browser?

Comment: from a google search it sometimes automatically gives it to you like that (i think i searched:what caused virgin ones launch failure) @ErinAnne